# Do I always need to use statistic for comparing two means?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

I have historical data on product sales for 2 years. How many items of the product were sold in each day. I need to compare if there is a difference in sales between Q1 2016 and Q1 2017. Do I really need to make a hypothesis test for this task? Or I can just compare the absolute number of sales per quarter? If so, what difference can be treated as significant? 5%?

Comment: It's business, so you can do whatever suits you. If you know statistics then use it, of course. You'll have to understand the assumptions though, that's why I wouldn't force non statisticians to use stats

Comment: Hi Aksakal, thank you for your message. So, how would statistician compare this data?

Comment: Because so many things can be different about time series, you need to start with defining what is being different. Is it the average level? Is it a seasonal pattern? Is it a trend? etc. Do exploratory analysis, meaning plot the data and look at it, get means and variances, compare them. This will help you understand what is interesting to you, then you can form a statistical hypothesis about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no.  The absolute number of sales is what your business saw, and comparing them in a matter-of-fact manner is often sufficient for giving a performance update.

That being said, the purpose of statistics is to show which trends are real vs those that aren't.  In business, this prevents over-reactions to noisy data.  To determine what kind of difference is significant, you could use daily data in 2016 and 2017 to get a sense of variability and conduct a significance test.

Perhaps most important practically, make sure you adjust sales for the extra day in Q1 2016, caused by a leap year.